# why componentDidMount() is empty in state?

Tags: reactjs

I want to create pagination.

And to do that I get an array of products in JSON and want to set to another class the length of the array.

But unfortunately probably because I use componentDidMount () it comes before the data is set so I get an empty array. What can be done to get the array?

The first class is-

```
class GetAllProducts extends React.Component {
    constructor () {
        super ();
        this.state = {
            ProductData: []
        }
    }
    state = {
        val: ''
    }
    componentDidMount () {
        axios.get ("https: // localhost: 44330 / api / values") .then (response => {
            //console.log(response.data);
            this.setState ({
                ProductData: response.data
            });
        });
    }
```

Which receives JSON of products.
I tested it and it works great and gets an array of all the products.

But that I do

```
 render () {
     const membersToRender = this.state.ProductData;
     const numOfRows = membersToRender.length;
     


     return (
         <div>
             <Navigation productCount = {numOfRows} />
         </div>
     );
```

And it calls the class Navigatuin and set to it the length of the array.

```
class Navigation extends React.Component {

 constructor (props) {
     super (props);
     this.state = {
         count: props.productCount, name: props.name
     };
 }
 render () {
     const {count} = this.state;
     console.log (this.stat);
```

But in the state I get the array empty.

How can I get the array in the other class?

Regards

Comment: `console.log (this.stat);` - there's a typo here.

Comment: You have to handle rendering befote the data is available. (Or wait for the data and delay UX.)

Comment: @Dave Newton First of all thank you so much for the help! But unfortunately I did not find how to do it (this is my first project in React)

Comment: I know there's a lot to take in :) I would recommend searching for tutorials on React with Ajax or similar; this is a very common problem--but like with a lot of React, there are many ways to deal with it. The easiest is to just assume the data might be false-y (e.g., undefined, empty, etc.) and use conditional rendering to handle that case. Once the data is there that same condition can be used to render the data.

Comment: @Dave Newton I'm really confused, I see you're trying to explain to me but I really can not understand. I have read articles on the above topics but I only see that it is a conditional statement. I could not understand how I define for him to call a function only after it is loaded